# Is there any flow diagram for laravel framework?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, workflow

I am learning laravel 8. I am getting confused visualizing how the whole thing works like request respond cycle, routes etc.
Is there any source where the whole laravel working scheme is visualized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this image from google. Hope this is clear to you. The basic flow you need to remember:

- Define Route
- Call Controller@method for that route
- Call Model to Query the database
- Pass data to a blade view file
- render that blade view file for user to see

There are many more things come in when you start developing properly. EG:
`Events, Jobs, Mailables, Notifications`

---

[image]

[image]